# ChatCompletion function gone from openai module

Tags: python, module, openai-api, chatgpt-api

When I run code that uses openai.ChatCompletion:

```
import openai
openai.api_key = "removed for obvious reasons"

completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello world!"}])
print(completion.choices[0].message.content)
```

it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\genos' ai\Documents\Code\openai-quickstart-python\text3.py", line 4, in <module>
    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello world!"}])
AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'ChatCompletion'. Did you mean: 'Completion'?
```

So I ran `print(str(openai.__all__))` to check the modules and it gives me

```
['APIError', 'Answer', 'Classification', 'Completion', 'Customer', 'Edit', 'Deployment', 'Embedding', 'Engine', 'ErrorObject', 'File', 'FineTune', 'InvalidRequestError', 'Model', 'OpenAIError', 'Search', 'api_base', 'api_key', 'api_type', 'api_key_path', 'api_version', 'app_info', 'ca_bundle_path', 'debug', 'enable_elemetry', 'log', 'organization', 'proxy', 'verify_ssl_certs']
```

no sight of ChatCompletion.

I'm using the latest version of the openai module, 0.27.4. I uninstalled and reinstalled the module through pip, but ChatCompletion is still not there.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip --version` and `python --version` and verify you are installing packages with the same python engine you are running your code with.

You could additionally compare the package version pip is installing with the version your environment is running:

`pip show openai`

`python -c "import openai; print(openai.__version__)"`

Hopefully that gets you enough information to resolve your environment issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error -- if you are using a jupyter notebook, just restart your kernel after you upgrade openai!

1. `pip install --upgrade openai`
2. restart kernel and it should work!

Answer (score -2):

Try `pip install --upgrade openai` and check `pip show openai` after restarting the kernel.

Sometimes, the kernel doesn't pick up the new package installed.